# How to wrap all `ul` elements in `div` with JQuery automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to wrap all `ul` elements in `div` with JQuery automatically?

```
<div id="my_uls">
  <ul>
   <li>Item one</li>
   <li>Item two
       <ul>
          <li>Item one of two</li> 
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But what I want:

```
<div id="my_uls">
   <div>
    <ul>
       <li>Item one</li>
       <li>Item two
           <div>
               <ul>
                  <li>Item one of two</li> 
              </ul>
          </div>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *automatically*? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried `$('my_uls ul').wrap('<div></div>')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `wrap` function for this

```
<scrpt>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var myuls = $("#my_uls").find("ul");
        for(var i=0;i<myuls.length;i++){
            $(myuls[i]).wrap("<div></div>");
        }
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.wrap()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul").wrap("<div />");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_uls">
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two
      <ul>
        <li>Item one of two</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: After your answer, I've understood what OP meant.

Comment: @JakubJankowski Ha ha... Even I was confused. Hence the time taken.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#my_uls ul')`, This will refer all your `ul` inside the `div`.

if you need the 1st `ul` only

`$('#my_uls ul:not(#my_uls ul ul)')`.