# How to append or insert a element as a wrapper/container of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `<ul>`'s in the DOM and I want to wrap those two `<ul>`'s into one wrapper div using **javascript/jquery**.

Is there any way to do so?

The original nodes are like this:

```html
<ul id="item-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="product-list">
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add wrapper div around those `ul` and it should look like this:

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="item-list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="product-list">
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above insertion should come from JavaScript or jquery only.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/wrapall

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap all \`ul\` elements in \`div\` with JQuery automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872428/how-to-wrap-all-ul-elements-in-div-with-jquery-automatically)

Comment: Give both `<ul>`'s a common class name let's say 'example'. Then you can simply do `$(".example").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper' />");`

Comment: maybe it helps https://codepen.io/Atilla_Pehlivan/pen/gOggarZ (not jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) like the following way:

```js
$('#item-list, #product-list').wrapAll( "<div id='container'></div>" );
```

```css
#container{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="item-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="product-list">
    <li>Product 1</li>
    <li>Product 2</li>
    <li>Product 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer perfectly applied to my issue, resolved my issue very fast :).